# Anonymous Types syntax in .net web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

As you can see in the following code I 'm going to use anonymous type to receive two different results in one IActionResult method.

```
var due = await (from d in db.Due
                 join a in db.ApartmentType
                 on d.ApartmentTypeId equals a.Id
                 ...
                 select new
                 {
                     ...

                 }).ToArrayAsync();

var sum_due = (from d in db.Due
              join a in db.ApartmentType
              on d.ApartmentTypeId equals a.Id
              ...
              select d.Amount).Sum();

var t = (due, sum_due);
return Ok($"{t.due}" + $"{t.sum_due}");
```

the first variable is a LINQ query and the second variable is a number.
When I return each variable one by one like this

```
return Ok(t.due)
```

Or

```
return Ok(t.sum_due)
```

I receive correct response, but when I combine them by tuples I receive none.

I'd like to know if I can combine them or I should use another way?

Comment: The serializer might not support `ValueTuple`s, why don't you use an anonymous object instead (or, better, an actual class)?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thank you for your comment.
Can you explain more?

Comment: `return Ok((due, sum_due));` if you want it in tuple.. A better way would be `return Ok(new {due, sum_due});`

Comment: @Andy Thank you Andy.
It worked. Please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: The question was how to use tuples, not  how NOT to use tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation is wrong for how you are returning a tuple. Try this:

```
return Ok((due, sum_due));
```

But, A better way would be

```
return Ok(new {due, sum_due});
```

That will give the caller context of what's returned.

Answer (score 0):

I personaly never used Tuples in my life. Anonimous were always enough and more comfortable for me. But if you need tuples for some reason,  tuples can be used with Action result.

This is a demo that was tested in postman

```
[Route("~/api/GetTuple")]
public  ActionResult<Tuple<int,int>> Get()
{
 return Ok(Tuple.Create(100, 200));
}
```

Result

```
{
    "item1": 100,
    "item2": 200
}
```

Comment: Why? Why not just do `public IActionResult Get() => Ok((100,200));`

Comment: I am agree with you. The question was why Tuple doesn' t work with ActionResult.

Comment: It does work with `IActionResult` -- his implementation is wrong.

Comment: This might work but returning data without names from a service is probably a bad idea from a support perspective.

Comment: The question was how to use tuples. I just  showed the example. If the question was  how NOT to use tuples i would give another answer.